# Logic error with my range-for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I'm studying C++ as a beginner (I started 2 months ago) and I have a problem with my simple code. I tried to set the value of each element in this vector to 0 but I can't understand why it doesn't work :

```
vector<int> numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; 

for (int x : numbers) x = 0;
```

I know that I may sound stupid but I am a beginner. If I try to do the same thing with a traditionally for loop it works, why ?

Comment: It seems the misunderstanding that the proposal on [on paper n3853](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3853.htm) tries to fix; I think that you will find it interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not change the values in the array, because in each iteration the value in the array is assigned to to x and you are changing x and not the value in the array.

Basically the range based loop is similar to the following ordinary for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i++)
{
     int x = numbers[i];

     //your code
}
```

.

For more information check out the c++ documentation:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for .
It states:

> range_expression is evaluated to determine the sequence or range to
>   iterate. Each element of the sequence, in turn, is dereferenced and
>   assigned to the variable with the type and name given in
>   range_declaration.

Also you will find there the example "Shmil The Cat" has posted and more examples which will help you understand how the range loop works.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int& x : numbers) x = 0;
```

In order to *mutate* the container elements one shall use reference for the range-loop iterating variable (by default, the iterating variable is a *copy* of the current iterated element)

Comment: to explain: range-based for loop takes parameter by value unless you specify to take by reference

Answer (score 1):

It does not work, you don't have any reference to the elements in the array via your `foreach`. Think about this, you are retrieving elements in array `numbers` and making a copy of copy in `x` which does not have reference. so any changes that x undergoes does not reflect in numbers arrays.

so work how `@Shmil The Cat` suggested. or traditional way will also do the job like you said.

Answer (score 1):

The items of vector are not assigned the value (zero in this case)because  ranged based loops consider container as copy of original until explicitly passed the reference of original container.

Do use

```
for (int& x : numbers) x = 0;
```

as suggested by @Shmil The Cat

Answer (score 0):

To help you understand, here is how you can read the below:

For every element in *numbers*, **copy** data into *x* and set *x* to 0. // Now this doesn't touch the value in the vector.

```
for (int x : numbers) 
    x = 0;
```

Reading the below loop:
For every element in *numbers*, make a *reference* to it, and change the value through the reference to 0. This on the other hand, changes the values in the vector.

```
for (int &x : numbers)
    x = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to set a particular value to all elements it would be better to use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)

```
std::fill(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0);
```